# Android - Gridview with Custom BaseAdapter, get clicked View at position

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I have created a gridview which displays the letters of the alphabet. I populate the gridview with a string array using a custom BaseAdapter.

What i want to do is to be able to get the `Button` View at a position in the GridView.

For example i want to be able from my `gridView.setOnItemClickListener();` to get-set the BackgroundColor of the Button that was clicked.

So far i am able to get the just the text form the string array at a position, but i don't know how i can get the clicked Button.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myGridView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:numColumns="7" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/feedback"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**cell.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/grid_item"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="05"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView text;
    private GridView gridView;
    private final String[] items = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedback);

        gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.myGridView);
        CustomGridAdapter gridAdapter = new CustomGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                text.setText((String) (gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)));
                Log.i("ITEM_CLICKED", "" + (String) (gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**CustomGridAdapter**

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String[] items;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
        }
        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item);
        button.setText(items[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Here is how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. I just changed my cell.xml to :

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid_item"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="05"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>
    </Button>
```

And then i could get any button by doing this:

```
Button button = (Button) gridView.getChildAt(position);
```

Answer (score 2):

1) If you need only to change bg color or smth else - you'd better use selectors.

2) In you example you don't have to inflate the xml file and then find button, you can create a button dynamically and then return this button directly.

3) If you have to inflate complicated view - in you onItemClickListener you can get your view by adapter\gridview.getItem and then, when you receive your view it's possible to perform findViewById and find all necessary views.

Answer (score 1):

In onItemClick()

```
gridAdapter.itemSelected = position;
```

in CustomGridAdapter:

```
public int itemSelected = -1;

getView(..)

    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedback);
    if (itemSelected == position) {            
        tv.setBackgroundColor(int selectedcolor);
    } else {
        tv.setBackgroundColor(int unselectcolor);
    }
```